# What are the app state/s when this method gets called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am implementing push notification in my iOS app.

I am supposed to display some custom View Controller in case the user opens (supposing the app is already running in background) the app from a push notification.

I am implementing this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PushNotificationReceived" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}
```

I checked the documentation, it says this method gets called whether app is in background or foreground. The system may call it second time when the app is about to enter the foreground, so I am wondering, is the code inside if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) { } going to execute.

Also, there is already some handling of the push notification inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, which only gets called at app launch. I guess I should remove it from there as, it may display that View Controller twice.

Please let me know you opinion if you have experience with this issues.

Comment: Put in a couple of NSLog and take a look at the output.

Answer (score 1):

actually I'm not getting your point.

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called **ONLY** if the app is active and **NOT** in **background**. So why do you need to check the `state`?

Then, if the app is in **background** the device receive the push notification, than if the user tap on that, **it is opened the app and that method is called**.

Otherwise if you open the app **without tap on the notification**, that method it is **not called**.

Comment: Matteo, thanks! I actually use the newest method (as in the question code) which is a bit different. If you check the docs, there is a note "...the system may call this method again when your app is about to enter the foreground...'. I was wondering why "may call" and not "will call", and is it guaranteed that the app state is UIApplicationStateActive when the app open after tapping on the push notification banner.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple documentation for the related method:

```
//This method will be invoked even if the application was launched or resumed because of the remote notification. 
//The respective delegate methods will be invoked first.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Therefore, if you implement the above delegate method, you should **NOT** handle push notifications in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` because the above method will be called even if application is just launching because of the push notification.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]` will have value `UIApplicationStateActive` only if you application was in foreground at the time push notification is received.

For the case when your application was in background or not running when a push notification is received, there are two scenarios:

1. `remote-notification` is enabled in UIBackgroundModes. In this case, the above method **may** be called **two** times. When the push notification is just received to device, the above method will be called with applicationState having value `UIApplicationStateBackground`. If user taps to presented push notification, the method will be called again, this time having applicationState value `UIApplicationStateInactive`.
2. `remote-notification` is NOT enabled in UIBackgroundModes. In this case, the method will be called **only** when user tapped to presented push notification.